# Button must clicked when keyboard shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have scrollView, where I have textFields and buttons. So when keyboard is opening and user tap button, action for this button will be done. It is right by Apple Guideleness or in the first must keyboard close and second tap by button after that will be done button's action? Maybe you can give me link on apple guideleness or other document where it is write about

Comment: It does not metter which method called in which menner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No specific Apple Guide for these steps, the right process depends on your business logic. Only one guide is to keep on high level of user experience!

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

no issues ...but better to resign keyboard